# One to many join joining to same record twice

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to join this table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BATCH")
public class Batch {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="BATCH_ID")
    private List<BatchDelivery> batchDeliveryList;

    public List<BatchDelivery> getBatchDeliveryList() {
        return batchDeliveryList;
    }

    public void setBatchDeliveryList(
        List<BatchDelivery> batchDeliveryList) {
        this.batchDeliveryList = batchDeliveryList;
    }
```

to the following table. The primary key in the `BATCH` table is `ID`. The foreign key in the `BATCH_DELIVERY` table to the `BATCH` table is `BATCH_ID`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BATCH_DELIVERY")
public class BatchDelivery {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BATCH_ID")
    private int batchId;

    // Other fields, get/set here

}
```

I have 2 `BATCH_DELIVERY` objects for 1 `BATCH` in the database so when Hibernate queries the database, I would expect both of the `BATCH_DELIVERY` objects to be in `BATCH`'s `batchDeliveryList`.

But, what I get is 2 *identical* `BATCH_DELIVERY` objects in `BATCH`'s `batchDeliveryList`. Why does Hibernate see that 2 objects match, but returns the same one twice?

**Edit**
Code that I use to load the Entity:

```
@Test
public void thatCourtCallsBatchDeliveryJoinWorks() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Batch batch = null;
    int id = 555;

    try {
        batch = (Batch)session.get(Batch.class, id);            
        Hibernate.initialize(Batch.getBatchDeliveryList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("thatBatchDeliveryJoinWorks Exception", e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Note: I'm aware there's no assertion in this test yet. When I debug it and examine the List held by the `Batch` object, I see that the `BatchDelivery` objects are identical. If I use a Set instead of a List, then only 1 `BatchDelivery` object gets added.

Comment: Could you please paste the rest of the code for each class? Also, have you implemented equals and hashCode for each class?

Comment: The rest of the code for each class is just more data members and corresponding getters/setters. No I haven't implemented equals and hashCode. Do joins not work unless they're implemented? I'm not a Hibernate expert.

Comment: Well, it depends how the entities are loaded. Because you haven't implemented hashCode or equals hibernate may think that it hasn't loaded the entities from the database an reloads them. Its generally good advice to always implement hashCode and equals when using Collections. See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode for more detail.

Comment: Thanks. I read through it. I also found a similar article in the meantime and implemented hashCode and equals, but I still have the same issue. I tested that equals works correctly...

Comment: Can you post the code you use to load the entity?

Comment: @AlanHay I added it to the post

Comment: Assuming the static call to Batch is a typo, I cannot see anything obvious. You would need to post the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `BatchDelivery` did not have a primary key, so joining on its non-unique ID was producing unexpected results. I annotated a second field in `BatchDelivery` as `@Id` to create a compound key.